# Адаптивная картина в HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive

Цель следующая - добиться ресайза картинки в меньшую сторону от оригинального разрешения.
Я использовал следующий css код:

```
.image {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Html:

```
<div>
  <img class="image" style="width: 171.96mm; height: 145.77mm;" src="http://localhost:88/SanovoNext/ImageHandler.aspx?url=http://doccentermedia//DCProImages/STG-NL/general%20topic/Jansen%20logo.jpg&amp;w=171.96mm&amp;h=145.77mm&amp;ro=0&amp;mode=xhtmlGen&amp;max_width=&amp;max_height=&amp;dpi=&amp;reportId=" original_height="145.77mm" original_width="171.96mm">
</div>
```

Но картинка ресайзится только по ширине, по высоте - игнорируется. Почему так? Как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разметку в студию

Comment: У Вас на скриншоте IE, с этим браузером постоянно какая то лажа

Comment: @aepot добавил разметку, но она вроде самая обычная

Comment: `style="width: 171.96mm; height: 145.77mm;"` стиль на элементе имеет приоритет выше, чем в css. Ваш `height: auto` никак не учитывается. Мне казалось, это должно быть очевидно. И непонятно, зачем одно и то же задавать в двух местах.

Comment: @aepot в html размеры задаются для правильного отображения картинки в документе.
Но хочу сделать "адаптивную картинку", чтобы при уменьшении окна браузера - картинка становилась меньше. При увеличении окна браузера - картинки увеличивалась до оригинальных размеров указанных в html style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение ( !important; ставит приоритет на сss селектор ):

```
.image 
    {
        max-width: calc(100% - 10mm);
        height: auto !important;
    }
```